# Php misbehave when you click "open in a new tab" and then go to the next page (eshop)

Tags: php, ajax, hyperlink

i have an issue with php. There is a list of products, a search box (for different types of products) and a next-previous page (to show the next page containing the products. This works normally but, when a user selects some of the categories in the search box, clicks on a product with "open in an new tab", when he continues the scrolling on the same page and selects next page, the search box resets as well as the http link. This happens only when someone clicks on a product to be shown to a new tab and continues his searching. I have now idea how this can occur, since everything else is working normally. I am attaching an example of the way that the next page button creates the http link and maybe there is something wrong there.
So the main question is what goes wrong when a user uses right click "open in a new tab" and in the main page that shows the products, after clicking the next page, everything resets except category and type. (i have already tried to use more variables of the products in the example below but it still resets). Any ideas??

type, type1 and category are variables of the products stored in SQL database for each product and they appear in the search box.  The $lang[''] is used to show in the link the variable cat in different languages. $nume stores the total number of records in the table (created for the products) and $eu stores the number of products on current page.

```
if ($type != "ALL" &&  $category != "ALL" &&  $type1 != "" )
{
    if ($nume - $eu <= $limit)
echo "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)'onclick=\"ajaxCall('/".$lang['nameOfProducts']."/".$cat."/".$lang['typ']."/$type1/page".($l-1)."/','','".($l-1)."','$totalPages');\">".($l-1)."</a></li>
....}";
```

Comment: This is what happens when you output _bogus_ links that are not really links, but are (ab-)used as JavaScript triggers … `<a href='javascript:void(0)'onclick=\"ajaxCall(…` – there _is_ nothing to open in a new tab here, this doesn’t _link_ to anything. The onclick handler however still fires on a right click, and performs your AJAX request in the background (and in the current tab.)

Comment: Yes, however this is used when the user clicks "next page". it works normally, except in the case the user has previously right clicked a product with open in a new tab. So this action creates the reaction of reseting the link above and resets all the selected variables for the search of the product except for category and type.

Comment: I mean that if the user just scrolls down and then goes to the next page, everything is ok.

Comment: Too little information here on what is actually going on. We have no idea what happens inside your system, when the user opens a product link in a new tab.

Comment: Where would you suggest for me to look for it.. It is a normal website with many products. You can use the search box to select the size the color etc and then you can see the products. You click on one to open in a new tab (to see it more carefully later) and you continue the scroll down. when you click next page, all the filters reset leaving category and type. There may be something wrong in the code that creates the previous and next page and not in the filters section in my opinion. My issue is that i dont know what i am looking for, as a bug or a false code..

Comment: Well I’d start looking at how the search criteria are passed from the search box to the server. Are they stored in a session on the server side, is it all kept in JS variables on the client (and the values get send with every new request, when moving to a previous or next result page), … And into what happens when one of those product links is opened, does that trigger any changes in JS variables or session contents.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and your time .. I will start with the search criteria